# Vue - removing all spaces from a string from Firestore database

Tags: vuejs2

I am still learning Vue.  I know how to remove all spaces from a string using Javascript, such as:

```
var str = " a b    c d e   f g   ";
var newStr = str.replace(/\s+/g, '');
```

I can't figure out how to implement this in Vue.

I would like to take a string from my Firestore database, say a field called "title1", with a value of "This is my string" and remove all spaces so it says "Thisismystring".  Then I want to be able to use that string in my Vue app in the same way I would use title1... like a variable called title1nospaces.

I'm not sure if I should be using a computed property or a method.  Anything I've tried always comes back as "title1nospaces" is not defined on the instance but is referenced during render".

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var str = " This is a test ";   
var new_str = str.split(' ').join('');

console.log(new_str); // 'Thisisatest'
```

Answer (score 0):

In your vue app, you should add a mixin and in that mixin you should implement a method that takes an input with spaces and it should return the output as a string without a spaces (or formatted string).

E.g.

```
let myApp = new Vue({
   mixins: [CommonUtils],
});
```

CommonUtils.js code ( I am using ES6 syntax):

```
export default {
  methods: {
     myStringFormattingFun(input) {
        // Do your magic and return the formatted string

     }

  }
}
```

OR you can just implement the function in your myApp component (main component).